# How can i create fast-links for my website on search engines?

Tags: wordpress, search-engine

I'm trying to find a specific word here. What do we call when we type a famous website on a search engine (for example imdb.com) and under the search result appears fast-links like IMDB Top 250, Charts, New Movies Coming Soon etc. And how can i implement that using Wordpress?
Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. SEO questions are better suited at **[Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)**. Please be sure to read their [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/about) and to search the site before asking your question as SEO has been covered in depth there.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that using wordpress. I think that is called as backlinking.

If you want that, then build a website as good as imdb.com and you'll get the so called "fast links".